# ¿Cómo cubrir la parte catch de un método void?

Tags: java, junit, pruebas-unitarias, mockito

Tengo este metodo

```
@Secured(value = { "fiscal", "sistemas" })
public void copiarFichero(Integer idFichero, String nombreFichero) {
    logger.debug("copiarFichero: Se copia el fichero: " + nombreFichero);
    try {
        gestorDocumental.copiarDocumento(idFichero, nombreFichero);
    } catch (ServicioWebException e) {
        logger.error("copiarFichero: Error " + e.getMessage()
                + e.getCause());
    }
}
```

cubro la parte del try pero la del catch no soy capaz no se como modificar el test para hacer un null pointer

```
@Test
public void copiarFichero() {
    try {
        Mockito.doAnswer(new Answer<Void>() {
            public Void answer(InvocationOnMock invocation)
                    throws Throwable {
                return null;
            }
        }).when(gestorDocumental)
                .copiarDocumento(Mockito.anyInt(), Mockito.anyString());
    } catch (ServicioWebException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    instance.copiarFichero(1, "asf");
    
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Creo que lo que necesitas es Mockito.doThrow:

```
doThrow(new ServicioWebException()).when(gestorDocumental)
            .copiarDocumento(Mockito.anyInt(), Mockito.anyString());
```

Comment: gracias era asi